# Tensorflow: batching labels with tf.train.batch

Tags: tensorflow

i have a piece of code

```
la=[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
onehot = tf.one_hot(la, depth=2)   #[[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]]
image_batch,labels_batch=tf.train.batch([resized_image,onehot],batch_size=2,num_threads=1)
```

when i run

> print(s.run([tf.shape(image_batch),labels_batch]))

it is batching all labes at a time,like

```
[array([ 2, 50, 50,  3]), array([[[ 1.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  1.],
    [ 0.,  1.],
    [ 0.,  1.],
    [ 0.,  1.]],

   [[ 1.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  1.],
    [ 0.,  1.],
    [ 0.,  1.],
    [ 0.,  1.]]], dtype=float32)]
```

it should output something like

```
[array([ 2, 50, 50,  3]), array([[[ 1.,  0.],

   [[ 1.,  0.]]], dtype=float32)]
```

doesn't it? as batch size is 2 and taking 2 images and it's corresponding labels at a time.
i'm new to CNN and machine learning.thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the **Tensorflow** documentation of **tf.train.batch** (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch),

[image]

Since the **enqueue_many=False** by default and your input **onehot** have the shape of **[10, 2]**, then the output (here **labels_batch**) shape become **[batch_size, 10, 2]**.

if the **enqueue_many=True**, then only the output (here **labels_batch**) will become **[batch_size,2]**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hii i'm getting _ValueError: Dimensions 50 and 10 are not compatible_ my resized_image shape is _([array([50, 50,  3])_  and onehot shape is 
_ array([10,  2])]_  ,Tensorflow documentation of tf.train.batch  says **all members of tensors should have the same size in the first dimension.**
i think,i have to reshape to [2,50,50,3] and [2,10,2]? can you please explain.

Comment: I think because you have 50 image samples and only 10 labels, isn't it?

Comment: no i have only 10 images each shaped [50,50,3].any suggestion?

Comment: so u mean your resized_image shape is [10,50,50,3] ?

Comment: no,it's [50,50,3]  and onehot is [10,2]  (i guess [10,50,50,3] where 1st dimension is channel )and then
`image_batch,label_batch=tf.train.batch([resized_image,onehot],enqueue_many=True,batch_size=2,num_threads=1)`
is it assuming 50 and 10 as channels???

Comment: No here, the resized_image shape should be [10,50,50,3] and the onehot shape should be [10,2], where 10 should be the number of samples.

Comment: ok,final doubt. i read images using a pipeline and resized all images using 
 `tf.image.resize_images(my_img, [50, 50])` and it is returning ` [array([50, 50,  3])]` when i print `tf.shape(resized_image)`,what is my mistake?am i missing something?

Comment: what is your my_img shape?